# Look at the following code. What is the value of output when it is printed?

Tags: java

```
int output = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        output += 3;
    }
}
System.out.println("Output is: " + output);
```

Look at the following code. What is the value of output when it is printed?

Could somebody help me on this question by telling me the value of `i`, please?

Comment: why don't you test yourself?

Comment: This is from a past paper so i wouldn't be able to test it

Comment: @JavaBeginner: Why do you think you're not able to test it? You just posted the code here. You **can** copy that code to a `main` method, compile and run.

Answer (score 2):

"Output is: 10"

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
```

Will go trough every number from 0 to 3.

```
if (i%2==0)
```

If the number is 0 or divisible by 2, you are going to add 3 to "output".

So it will add 3 to output when i is 0 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

> Could somebody help me on this question by telling me the value of i please ?

Sounds like a trick question.  If you truly are asking for the value of `i`, then it would be 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    if (i%2==0) {
      output+=3;
    } 
}
```

1) when i=0 and 0<4 and in if condition 0%2==0(0 mod 2) then output+=3 which is 4+3=7 finally i++ that means i=i+1 which is 0+1 = 1

2) Now i=1 and 1<4 and in if condition 1%2(1 mod 2) is not equal (=) 0 thus output+=3 statement will not execute and finally i++ that means i=i+1 which is 1+1 = 2

3) Now i=2 and 2<4 and in if condition 2%2==0(2 mod 2) then output+=3 which is 7+3=10 finally i++ that means i=i+1 which is 2+1 = 3

4) Now i=3 and 3<4 and in if condition 3%2(3 mod 2)  is not equal (=) 0 thus output+=3 statement will not execute and finally i++ that means i=i+1 which is 3+1 = 4

5) Now i=4 and 4 is not less then 4 thus end of the loop.

```
System.out.println("Output is: " + output);
```

Now printing output, which is 10.

So, output:

**Output is: 10**